# Inserting a value into an array list, and remove any duplicates

Tags: java, arrays

I've got an array list of an object

```
Table[] tables = new Table[10];
```

this list stores information about 10 players and their position goes from top 1 which is tables[0] and top 10 that equals to tables[9]

however, sometimes I need to put a value in between the array, and let's say the player name i'm putting in must be top 5, that means, top 5 goes to top 4, and from top 4 to 3.. and 3 to 2.. and so on, but I also need to check if those values contain the player name that I just added so in that case I gotta remove it, and put all the list back up, pretty much add 1, does anyone have suggestions on the best way to do this, the way i'm thinking on doing it is probably not the best.

Here is what I made so far... however it's not complete..

```
private void addToBoard(Player damaged, Player killer) {
    if(damaged.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(killer.getName())){
        return;
    }
    for(Table table : tables){
        if(table != null){
            if(table.currentPlayer.equalsIgnoreCase("No One")){
                table.currentPlayer = killer.getName();
                break;
            }else if(table.currentPlayer.equalsIgnoreCase(damaged.getName()) || table.currentPlayer.equalsIgnoreCase("Searching...")){              
                if(table.currentPlayer.equalsIgnoreCase(killer.getName())){
                    return;
                }
                if(table.currentPlayer.equalsIgnoreCase(killer.getName())){
                    return;
                    //update the list, and remove duplications
                }
                if(!table.currentPlayer.equalsIgnoreCase("Searching...")){
                    killer.chat("I killed "+damaged.getName()+" and now I am Top: "+table.topID+" gf :)");
                }
                table.currentPlayer = killer.getName();
                if(table.topID != 10){
                    //make a list on a hashmap with the key from 1 to 10
                    HashMap<Integer, Table> addAll = new HashMap<Integer, Table>();
                    //add the top
                    for(int i = 0; i < tables.length; i++){
                        addAll.put(tables[i].topID, tables[i]);
                    }
                    HashMap<Integer, Table> updated = new HashMap<Integer, Table>();
                    String oldPlayer;
                    for(Entry<Integer, Table> top : addAll.entrySet()){
                        if(top.getValue().currentPlayer.equalsIgnoreCase(damaged.getName())){
                            //dont add
                            oldPlayer = top.getValue().currentPlayer;
                            top.getValue().currentPlayer = killer.getName();
                            Table next = updated.get((top.getValue().topID+1));
                            next.currentPlayer = oldPlayer;
                            updated.put(next.topID, next);
                        }else{
                            if(updated.containsKey(top.getValue().topID)){
                                updated.put((top.getValue().topID+1), top.getValue());
                            }else{
                                updated.put(top.getValue().topID, top.getValue());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < tables.length; i++){
                        if(updated.get(i) != null){
                            tables[i] = updated.get(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }   
        }
    }

}
```

thanks!

Comment: Show an example of what you've tried to solve your issue

Comment: ugh.. I tried to do it but then i got lost lol.. here it is: http://hastebin.com/vofiqisore.avrasm

Comment: Well, we need to see an effort put towards solving your own problem before we provide assistance.

Comment: who said I'm not trying, i just don't think the way that I'm doing it is the best

Comment: Then, in your question, show us the code you did try. Even if it doesn't work.

Comment: hum, I already provided the link above

Comment: I know that, i'm just saying, for future reference, it's better to post the code in the question, not an external website.

Comment: alright, sorry I added it

Comment: @Stefan15ist And on stackoverflow there isn't a mob commenting. LoL

Comment: that is VERBOSE! if I ever saw it. Why not just have the players implement Comparable and use a list and sort them, your thing is crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use an array. Use a `List` instead, which supports `myList.add("New Guy", 4)` -- that is, adding players in a given position and displacing all others one step up. You could then remove the 11th (old 10th) with `myList.remove(10)`:

```
myList.add("New Guy", 4);
myList.remove(10);
```

You can do the same thing with arrays, but it is less readable:

```
// copies 4 elements from (old) pos. 4 to its new pos. 5
System.arraycopy(tables, 4, tables, 5, 4);
tables[4] = "New Guy";
```

Or use a loop, which is both hard to read (it has to go downwards to avoid losing information) and more verbose:

```
for (int i=9; i>=5; i--) tables[i] = tables[i-1];
tables[4] = "New Guy";
```